# how to deploy lightning message channel in vs code

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, developer-edition

I have created a lightning message service configuration file (.Xml) and while deploying it on right click of vs code and deploying it i am facing the  below  error

force-app\main\default\messageChannels\SampleMessageChannel.messageChannel-Meta.xml: Could not infer a metadata type

I am using devloper org not a sandbox or scratch so  i am unable to use sfdx force:source:push

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>SampleMessageChannel</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>Message Channel to pass data</description>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>lmsData</fieldName>
        <description>This is the field to pass data</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

How o deploy it in the source org

Comment: Here is an article I have written about [Create Lightning message channel in easy and faster way](https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/03/create-lightning-message-channel-in-salesforce-fast.html).

Comment: @RahulGawale i have followed your article and tried the steps it worked fine

Comment: If you use ".messageChannel-meta.xml" file type, try to change it to ".messageChannel". It helped me once.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this into the terminal, worked for me.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m LightningMessageChannel
```